# Appending two online features and keeping the attachments in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, features, append, attachments

I need append two online features and keep the attachments. The process consists of putting 12000 images in 4000 points, but if two features have different attachments and I need to keep both.

I tried to use the tool Append but I have two problem with this tool. First the process doesn't keep the attachments of one of the features and second I need do it this process in one online feature I can't have the the possibility to edit the online feature with the tool append.

The other alternative is put the images manually into points. The problem is the amount of attachments per point.
Could you tell about other structure or tool or ArcPy process to have a good successful result?